How to maximize $\mathbf{E}(XY) $ if we know the distribution of $X$ and $Y$
Given two discrete random variables (X) and (Y) with known distributions. The contingency table is provided:
\begin{array}{c|ccc|c}
  & Y=1 & Y=2 & Y=3 & \text{Total} \\
\hline
X=1 & a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & \mathbf{P}(X=1) = \frac{1}{2} \\
X=2 & a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & \mathbf{P}(X=2) = \frac{1}{4} \\
X=3 & a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & \mathbf{P}(X=3) = \frac{1}{4} \\
\hline
\text{Total} & \mathbf{P}(Y=1) = \frac{1}{3} & \mathbf{P}(Y=2) = \frac{1}{3} & \mathbf{P}(Y=3) = \frac{1}{3} & 1
\end{array}
We want to maximize $\mathbf{E}(XY) $. We have:
$\mathbf{E}(XY) = \sum_{i=1}^{3} \sum_{j=1}^{3} i \cdot j \cdot a_{ij} = a_{11} + 2a_{12} + 3a_{13} + 2a_{21} + 4a_{22} + 6a_{23} + 3a_{31} + 6a_{32} + 9a_{33}$
My idea is to maximize:
$a_{11} + 2a_{12} + 3a_{13} + 2a_{21} + 4a_{22} + 6a_{23} + 3a_{31} + 6a_{32} + 9a_{33}$
subject to the constraints:
\begin{align*}
a_{11} + a_{12} + a_{13} &= \frac{1}{2} \\
a_{21} + a_{22} + a_{23} &= \frac{1}{4} \\
a_{31} + a_{32} + a_{33} &= \frac{1}{4} \\
a_{11} + a_{21} + a_{31} &= \frac{1}{3} \\
a_{12} + a_{22} + a_{32} &= \frac{1}{3} \\
a_{13} + a_{23} + a_{33} &= \frac{1}{3} \\
0 \leq a_{ij} &\leq 1 \quad \forall i, j
\end{align*}
I wonder if this approach is correct and if there is a simpler way.

This looks correct and if you give this to any linear programming solver it should solve it nearly immediately.

There is a much more simple way. The solution to this problem is known, it is $\mathbb E[F_X^{-1}(U)F_Y^{-1}(U)]$, where $U$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$, and $F_X^{-1}$ resp. $F_Y^{-1}$ denotes the quantile function of the distribution of $X$ resp. $Y$. See for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comonotonicity.

@will    I don't understand this method; I've never seen it before. If you can provide it as a solution, it might help those who need it.

Let $f$, resp. $g$, be the quantile function of the distribution of $X$, resp. $Y$, that is
$$
f:u\in(0,1)\mapsto1_{\{u\le1/2\}}+2\cdot1_{\{1/2<u\le3/4\}}+3\cdot1_{\{u>3/4\}},\\
g:u\in(0,1)\mapsto1_{\{u\le1/3\}}+2\cdot1_{\{1/3<u\le2/3\}}+3\cdot1_{\{u>2/3\}}.
$$
Then, with $U$ uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$,
$$
\begin{align}
\max\mathbb E[XY]&=\mathbb E[f(U)g(U)]\\
&=\mathbb E[1_{\{U\le1/3\}}+2\cdot1_{\{1/3<U\le1/2\}}+4\cdot1_{\{1/2<U\le2/3\}}+6\cdot1_{\{2/3<U\le3/4\}}+9\cdot1_{\{U>3/4\}}]\\
&=\frac13+2\cdot\frac16+4\cdot\frac16+6\cdot\frac{1}{12}+9\cdot\frac14\\
&=\frac{49}{12},
\end{align}
$$
where the maximum is taken over all random variables $X$ and $Y$ with the given distributions.
Proofs of this statement can easily be found online. Useful keywords: comonotonic coupling, Hoeffding-Fréchet bounds.

@Wili
Thank you for the response, but with an online linear programming tool, I can't find your result. One question: why is this reasoning incorrect? We have E(XY) ≤ E(X)E(Y), and equality holds when X and Y are independent, so max E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)

Can you please give a coupling example where you find a bigger expected value with your linear programming tool?
Your reasoning fails because $\mathbb E[XY]\le\mathbb E[X]\mathbb E[Y]$ has no reason to be true. Take for instance $Y=X$ standard gaussian, you have $\mathbb E[XY]=1$ but $\mathbb E[X]\mathbb E[Y]=0$.

@Wili I had always believed that for two positive discrete random variables X and Y, we always have:
$ \mathbb{E}(XY) \leq \mathbb{E}(X) \mathbb{E}(Y) $
This is a direct consequence of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality applied in the space of random variables

This belief is wrong. Positiveness of values and positiveness of correlation (or equivalently scalar product) are two distinct things. Take for instance $X=U$ and $Y=U$ where $U$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$. Then $\mathbb E[XY]=1/3$ but $\mathbb E[X]\mathbb E[Y]=1/4$. That is no coincidence, I am using the fact that the comonotonic coupling between the distribution of $X$ and itself in that case is  $(X,X)$, so I know in my example that $\mathbb E[XY]$ is maximised for $(X,X)$.

I had made an error in an input. Your result is correct with the linear program.
